# Почему пишет Invalid reaction provided (only valid emoji are allowed) (caused by "messages.SendReaction")

Tags: python, pycharm, pyrogram

хочу сделать скрипт который отправляет реакцию на входящее сообщение.

код писал в pycharm

```
from pyrogram 
import Client, filters

app = Client("my_account")

@app.on_message(filters.text & filters.private)
async def echo(client, message):
    await app.send_reaction(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.id, emoji='')

app.run()
```

Comment: Какая у вас версия Pyrogram? Лично у меня вот так и всё работает: `>>> from importlib.metadata import version
>>> version('pyrogram')
'2.0.106'`

Comment: кодировка моего скрипта: `UTF-8`